# Как добавить 3 единицы на следующий элемент?

Tags: vector, c++

```
for(int number=0;number<=5;number++)
{
    v1.push_back(number);
}

v1[5]=2;
    vector <int>::iterator pCursor = v1.begin();

    for(int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << v1[i] << " ";
    }

    cout<<endl;
    if(*(v1.end() - 1) == 2)
    {
        for(pCursor = v1.begin(); pCursor < v1.end() ; pCursor++)
        {
            cout<< *pCursor<< " ";
            if(*pCursor % 3 == 0)
            { 
                pCursor = v1.insert(pCursor+1, 3, 1);
            }
        }
        cout<<"on delitsa na 2";
    }
```

Пробую вот так

```
pCursor = v1.insert(pCursor+1, 3, 1);
```

Но получаю непонятную ошибку

> 37    13[Error]
> no match for 'operator=' (operand
> types are 'std::vector<int>::iterator
> {aka
> **gnu_cxx::**normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >}' and 'void')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вектор в самом начале пустой, то строкой

```
   v1[5] = 2;
```

Вы уже приехали, то есть вышли за пределы вектора и дальше может быть все что угодно. Но оно не компилируется по той причине, что метод [insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) возвращает `void` в данном случае.

Comment: @KoVadim, он в самом начале 6 раз делает `push_back`, только с форматированием проблемы...

@Анатолийй, а разве итератор в цикле после вставки останется действительным?

Comment: да, не заметил там равно. Видимо потому, что я обычно так циклы не пишу.

Comment: Это точно. Я вообще эту "преамбулу" не сразу прочел.